# Is it possible to entirely disable the ability to set error_reporting?

Tags: php, error-reporting

I'm wondering if at the server level I can disable the ability for scripts to override `error_reporting` and `ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Edit: I know how to disable errors using .htaccess and on a script by script basis. What I am trying to do is disable the ability to override error settings entirely so our developers actually fix their issues and not hide behind a `error_reporting(0); ini_set('display_errors', 0);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use the [disable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) feature built into PHP. That will prevent them from even calling `ini_set` or `error_reporting` in the first place.

Add to php.ini:

`disable_functions = error_reporting,ini_set,shell_exec,etc...`

Comment: One issue I have with this is we want to disable *write* access to `error_reporting`, but *read* access should be OK.

Comment: I can recommend this even on production environments. Developers like to make their scripts "secure" by setting error_reporting to 0 somewhere during initialization, which makes debugging very difficult. But with display_errors off and only log_errors on, there is no reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

Many third party developers think they are smart by defining `error_reporting` for you. This needs to stop:

php.ini:

```ini
disable_functions = ini_set,error_reporting
```

PHP:

```php
if (!function_exists('error_reporting')) {
    function error_reporting(?int $error_level): int {
        // do not enable overriding of error_reporting
        return ini_get('error_reporting');
    }
}

if (!function_exists('ini_set')) {
    function ini_set(string $option, string|int|float|bool|null $value): bool {
        // return false to indicate failure
        return false;
    }
}
```

Only compatible with PHP 8+, because `disable_functions` will actually remove the function from PHP 8 onwards, so we can redeclare it, so those third party developers can continue their madness, but they cannot hide it towards you.

Answer (score -2):

If you add these lines to your .htaccess it should do the job for the entire site.

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_flag  log_errors off
```

If you want to do it on a script by script basis

From the PHP manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and found by doing a search for 'disable php error reporting'

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: I'm trying to disable the ability to set `error_reporting` entirely. We have lazy programmers who hide their crap code by setting `error_reporting(0)` at the top of their files and I want to completely disable their ability to do that.